# Расположение изображения по центру блока

Tags: css, img, position

Доброй ночи, интересует вопрос можно ли расположить изображение в блоке по центру? К примеру есть блок скажем 400х200 в нем изображение скажем 600х300 и оно располагается по дефолту top: 0; left: 0, если сделать изображению width: 100% оно займет всю ширину а по высоте обрежется, вот хочу уточнить можно ли как то средствами css расположить изображение по центру? Что то на подобие background-position: center center;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [центровкой фона](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552380/)

```css
.crop {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="crop" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/600x450&text=Covered%20to%20400x200');"></div>
<img src="http://placehold.it/600x450&text=Original%20is%20600x450" alt="Original size">
```

---

2. [позиционированием по центру](https://habrahabr.ru/post/238449/#comment_8012553)

```css
.crop {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
.crop img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="crop">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/600x450&text=Covered%20to%20400x200" alt="Covered Image" />
</div>
<img src="http://placehold.it/600x450&text=Original%20is%20600x450" alt="Original size">
```

Comment: Первый вариант совсем не в ту степь, да для фона его использование (must have и лучше не придумать), а вот второй вариант (если немного поиграться с высотами в принципе выполняет то что я и хотел. Правда думал что это реализуется немного проще.

Comment: @ConstantineShibaev Спасибо за обратную связь! А что "не в ту степь" в первом варианте? Хочу разобраться на будущее.

Comment: Ну в первом варианте используется все для позиционирования background-a, это если мне задавать изображение фоном блока. А меня интересует позиционирование изображения внутри блока. Чтобы в дальнейшем было проще добавлять и изменять кейсы с изображениями.

Comment: @ConstantineShibaev Спасибо. Разобрался.

Answer (score 1):

Можно.

http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-size

```
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: Да ну это совсем не то, и тем более оно же применяется только для фона а меня интересует поведение одного блока относительно другого (его родителя)